# Как заблокировать нажатие Button-a, если открыто какое-либо окно

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

У меня есть карта мира, в которой есть Button-ы запуска уровней, т.е. при нажатии на эту кнопку, выводится окошко с инфо, в которой есть кнопка "Играть". Но при открытом окошке срабатывают и те кнопки на карте мира, как это предотвратить, остановить рэйкаст? Можно ли создать слой, маску ил ичто-нибудь на этом открытом окне, чтобы дальше нее ничего не работало? Игра 2D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Могу посоветовать самый простейший способ: Создайте в вашем окне начала уровня дочерний Image на весь экран, выкрутите в его цвете альфа канал в минимум и картинка станет прозрачной, сделайте его в иерархии чайлдов самым первым.

Вуаля - вы сделали Fade панель :D этот Image будет прозрачен, но при этом будет перехватывать все клики мимо панели, а всё, что находится в иерархии ниже будет кликабельно)

В дальнейшем, если потребуется, можно будет прилепить на него реализацию отлова кликов, если потребуется закрывать панель по мисс клику)

Comment: в вебе все модальные окна так работают)